# bash script to run tests in multiple docker-compose environments

Tags: bash, batch-file, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

Need some help writing a script to automate a fairly simple process of running tests on several docker-compose environments on a windows host.

This is the manual process that I would like to automate:

1. Open a docker quickstart terminal
2. Setup 3 identical environments: `docker-compose -p test1 up -d && docker-compose -p test2 up -d && docker-compose -p test3 up -d`
3. Open 2 more docker terminals, and then run one of the following on each:

   1. `docker-compose-run -p test1 app ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js cuc-reports`
   2. `docker-compose-run -p test2 app ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js cuc-not-reports1`
   3. `docker-compose-run -p test3 app ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js cuc-not-reports2`
4. When all tests complete, tear down: `docker-compose -p test1 down && docker-compose -p test2 down && docker-compose -p test3 down`

I'm stuck pretty much in the beginning. I can open a docker machine shell but can't get it to change directories in order to execute step 2. I tried the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
src=$PWD/../../
cd "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox"
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh" cd $src && docker-compose -p test1 up -d && docker-compose -p test2 up -d && docker-compose -p test3 up -d
```

However the "cd $src" is not executed which causes the subsequent commands to fail.

Trying to generalize the things I think I need in order to run this script, I might summarize as follows:

- How can I pass commands to be executed once the docker shell loads (such as "cd ...")?
- How can I open multiple independent (docker) shells from the root shell and wait for them to finish executing their commands?

I intended to write the script for git-bash on windows, which is my preference, but suggestions for a windows batch script are also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it wasn't so hard in the end. Pretty messy and I'm sure it could be improved, but it does what I wanted (in the end I'm running 2 docker environments not 3 as it performs better with 4 cores). If anyone is interested where I got all this weirdness, just ask and I'll site some sources. Remember this answer is for Windows:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd `dirname $0`/../../

start bash -c 'docker-compose -p test1 up -d; sleep 3s; docker exec -i $(docker-compose -p test1 ps ros | grep -m 1 ros | cut -d " " -f1 ) ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js cucumber1; docker-compose -p test1 down; bash'
start bash -c 'docker-compose -p test2 up -d; sleep 3s; docker exec -i $(docker-compose -p test2 ps ros | grep -m 1 ros | cut -d " " -f1 ) ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js cucumber2; docker-compose -p test2 down; bash'
sleep 5s
start bash -c "docker stats $(docker ps | awk '{if(NR>1) print $NF}')"
```